# How to execute only click event of selected element with class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var elements = {
      element_no : 1,
      addNewElement : function(){
        var html = '';
        html +='<div class="test" id="test-'+ elements.element_no +'">Element No '+ elements.element_no;
        html +='<input type="file" id="test-file-'+ elements.element_no +'" />';
        html +='<input type="hidden" id="test-path-'+ elements.element_no +'" />';
        html +='</div>';
        $(html).hide().appendTo("#input-fields").slideDown("fast");
        
        $('#test-'+ elements.element_no).click(function(){
          var this_element_id = $(this).attr('id');
          var part_id = this_element_id.split('-').pop(1);
          var target_id = 'test-file-'+ part_id;
          
          // HERE I HAVE PROBLME
          // IF I HAVE TWO ELEMENT IT RUN TWO TIMES
          // IF I HAVE THREE OR MORE ELEMENTS IT RUNS ACCORDING TO THE NO OF ELEMENTS
          // WITH SAME CLASS,
          $(target_id).trigger("click");
          console.log(target_id);
        });
        elements.element_no++;
      }
  }

  $('#addNewElement').click(function(){
    elements.addNewElement();
  });
 
});
```

```css
.test{
  background:#ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}

button{
  padding : 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 220px;
  background:blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
input[type=file]{
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="descendants">
  <div id="input-fields"></div>
  <button id="addNewElement">Add New Field</button>
 </body>

</html>
```

My **Stack is Over Flowed**. I have a problem in execution of click event of class selector. When I clicks on an element which have class that has a click event attached with. It executes multiple time, I mean if I have two elements with the target class then click event of the class runs two time and I have three elements of that class is executes three time.

I want to execute only one click.

You can view the code at this.

Comment: Please include your code in the question and improve the formatting of your question.

Comment: 1. include your code, 2. element classes have nothing to do with click event handlers, only with the way of how you get the elements from the DOM. 3. Your problem is most likely that you are attaching event handlers within a loop and are not targeting the proper element, we will need your HTML as well as your javascript most likly

Comment: @Waqas Khan your code needs to be included in the question, not as an external resource link. Also see the https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  There is no need to expose and burden us with the entire page when you have a localized issue\

Comment: Thanks for reply Sir. Sorry, I am new here and don't know how to use this form. kindly view my code at his link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/347707/)

Comment: @WaqasKhan I simply cannot, there is too much of it. It is not the pure minimal most essential question, it is an entire form with a bunch of other code on top of it, which makes it far wider then your question. Make another fiddle, issolate the issue and post only THAT part of the code, then we can view what is wrong with it. Opening that link I do not even know where to begin

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cau8sL0b/2/ here is a fiddle example on how your question should be posted, this one works though, so show us how yours doesnt

Comment: @Dellirium Thanks for your reply. Now I created minimal example of the code please check it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem in your code is not where you identified it to be, in fact it is a bit up ahead, here:

```
$('.test').click(function(){.....
```

This is being executed EVERY time you click the "Add new" button.
And what this does is the following:

"Select all elements that have a class `.test` and attach a handler to them". So when you click the button for the first time, you:

1. Create a new element (total of 1)
2. Attach a handler to all the elements

When you click the button again:

1. Create another new element (total of 2 now)
2. Attach a handler to ALL the elements (so the first button now has 2 handlers while the new one only has one)

If you repeat this multiple times, every time you click a button you attach a handler to all the previous ones, in addition to the new button. You can verify this by clicking a new button 3-4 times then clicking on the LAST added element, you will see it will only print out ONE line. But if you click the FIRST button it will print out however many elements you have.

To solve this you simply need to change:

```
$('.test').click(function(){.....
```

to

```
$('#test-' + elements.element_no).click(function(){....
```

The goal here is to only select the ONE element you have added, we can do this, in the example you gave by the ID of the element, instead of the class. If your elements were to not have a unique way to identify them, you would then need to change the way you create them (in other words actually use `document.createElement('TAG')` instead of using the `.innerHTML` hack the way you do.

Comment: Glad to help, for next time just remember to post minimum examples and straight to the point questions to avoid getting negative points. Cheers